# Easton Axis and Axis Traditional - are they basically the same?

Tags: gear, archery, arrows

There are two shafts from Easton. The "Axis" and its younger brother the "Axis Traditional". Both of them are full featured carbon arrows but the latter one has a wooden design.

[image: Axis Traditional]

I've heard that these two shafts are basically completely similar except for this wood/non-wood design. Is this right? This concerns me because the traditional shaft is more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

The Easton Traditional are slightly heavier GPI because (I think) of their wood decal wrap.

The [400 spine Trad is 4.9 GPI](https://eastonhunting.com/target/5mm-axis-traditional/) where the [same spine in the ST is 4.0 GPI](https://eastonhunting.com/target/5mm-axis/).

There are a few other minor differences in outside diameter, but all the components are otherwise identical.